# Getting a random hash instead of image url

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

Here's the code snippet.

```
<img :src="./assets/img/stylechip-icon.png" alt="icon">
```

When I inspected the element I get this `random hash`.

[image]

Why I am getting this `random hash` and how to fix it?

Comment: the image is encoded in base64: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: That **is** an image url. See: [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).  It's saving you a "concrete" HTTP request.

Answer (score 3):

You have [vue](/questions/tagged/vue) tagged so I'm assuming you are using [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) and by extension [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

What you are seeing **is** an image URL.  It is a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

The project template created by vue-cli includes [url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader) and/or [img-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/img-loader) which pulls in a resource referenced in your source code, and base64 encodes it to a data URL whenever you build.  This allows you save a network request whenever you run your web application.

If you want to disable this feature, look for a a rule that matches the your file in your webpack configuration files.  In the vue-cli template, it is likely in `/build/webpack.base.conf.js` and the rule to remove should look similar to:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is happening because of webpack, so is there any configuration we can use to disable this.

Comment: Why do you want to disable it? It’s the same as a normal image load, except faster because there’s one less separate network request.

Comment: (That said, if you don’t want it, remove img-loader from your configuration. )

Comment: @YashuMittal see my edit.  However, you should probably add in your question *why* you want to disable this feature.  The action it is doing now is to save you a request.

Comment: That I already know, that it improves the performance of the Vue application.

Comment: Disabling this would *not* improve the performance of your application. It would make it (very slightly) less performant.

Comment: @YashuMittal I'm not exactly sure how to answer your question any further.  If this post answered your question, please consider accepting it as the solution.

Answer (score -1):

vue convert your image into base64.